# Mock DB Connection

Tags: python, database, mocking, flask-sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I'd like to mock a DB connection and execute. I am using SQLAlchemy. This is inside my `__init__.py` file

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(ANALYTICS_CONFIG)
app.json_encoder = ModelEncoder

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Then in my model I have the following function:

```
def get_campaigns(self, start, end, columns, filter=None):
        page_view = PageView.__table__

        unique = self.get_attribution_subquery(start, end, filter)

        table_columns = text(', '.join(['campaign_' + c for c in columns]))
        where_clause =  text(' AND '.join(['campaign_%s IS NOT NULL' % c for c in columns]))

        join_clause = self.get_attribution_model_join_clause(unique)

        query = select([
            table_columns,
            func.count(page_view.c.id),
            func.count(unique.c.submission_id)
        ]).select_from(
            unique.join(
                page_view,
                join_clause
            )
        ).where(
            where_clause
        ).group_by(
            table_columns
        )

        result = db.engine.execute(query)

        result_columns = columns + ['views', 'conversions']

        campaigns = []
        for row in result:
            row = dict(zip(result_columns, row))

            row['conversionRate'] = self.get_rate(row['conversions'], row['views'])

            campaigns.append(row)

        return campaigns
```

I don't want to connect to the database, I'd like to fake the return of `db.engine.execute(query)`. I'm thinking of monkey patching but I'm unsure how to do this or how to approach this.

Comment: Then why don't you research around monkey patching some more? There are several libraries already to help you with this.

Comment: I'm reading about it but couldn't really figure it out, that's why I asked.

Comment: Then **be more specific**. See [mcve].